# How to make a program accept a line of different input-types from terminal in java?

Tags: java, variables, input, calculator

I have a quick question about an assignment which I have. I want to make a sort of a calculator which will read the input from user, use an if-else-loop to figure out what to do with it and then print the corresponding result. 
So if the user inputs: 4 * 5, I want the program to check for two ints, and with a inChar check the type of calculation needed, then an if-else-loop which will do the rest (I know how to write this part) but I need some help on how to write the scanner-sentences where it checks for the different types of input from one line. Hope you understood what I meant.

The part of code which I already have:

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
int a,b;
char c;
double sum;

System.out.println("Velkommen til en helt enkel kalkulator!");
System.out.println("Vennligst tast inn regnestykket, paa formen: tall, regneart, tall med mellomrom imellom hver input: ");

    String svar=input.nextLine();


if(c='*'){
    sum=a*b;
}else if(c='/'){
    sum=a/b;
}else if(c='+'){
    sum=a+b;
}else if(c='-'){
    sum=a-b;
}else{
    System.out.println("Regnearten var ikke forstaaelig. Programmet termineres.");
}
```

Comment: show part of code with scanner that you have..

Comment: Short and precise questions fetch more attention, just saying.

Answer (score 1):

Read your input line by line and parse it after that using either `String.split()` or `Pattern`. To read lines use either `Scanner` or `System.in` wrapped with `BufferedReader`

Answer (score 0):

I love [regular expressions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression)! So lets use one: `(\d+)\s*([*/+-])\s*(\d+)`

Broken down:

`\d+` = One or more digits

`\s*` = "Space" zero or more times

`[*/+-]` = One of `*`, `/`, `+`, or `-`

The parentheses "capture" the matched elements, so you can access them later. In java, use `Matcher.group(int)`, like shown in the fragment below:

```
//Do this only once in your program
Pattern calcPattern = Pattern.compile("(\\d+)\\s*([*/+-])\\s*(\\d+)");

//Do this in your loop
Matcher m = calcPattern.matcher(input.nextLine());
if (m.matches()) {
    a = Integer.parseInt(m.group(1)); //Get the first group (first set of digits)
    c = m.group(2); //Get the second group (operator)
    b = Integer.parseInt(m.group(3)); //Get the third group (second set of digits)
    //do stuff with a, b, and c
} else {
    System.out.println("Please enter a valid expression!");
}
```

As you progress in skill, the regular expression is easily extendable - replace (\d+) with (\d+(?:.?\d+)?) to accept numbers with decimals, for instance. Play around with an online regexp tester here: http://rubular.com/r/8VibLUpxqP

(Quick note: the double backslashes in the regular expression in the java code are necessary because you can't write a single backslash in a string - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/characters.html)